# Print composer problems Qgis 2.8 Wien with Google Satellite

Tags: qgis, printing, google, satellite

I am having serious problems in exporting a map (Google satellite map) linked to QGIS.

Using the print editor I clearly see the part of the map I want to print and also in the right scale, but when I save it as jpeg, the result is:
the correct map in a circle in the middle of the page, and all around it seems that Qgis is zooming at different scale on another part of the map [see attached file].

Any suggestion about it ? I don't want to save it as simple screenshot  because I need an HD file.

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zx6VF.jpg)

Comment: several threads on this subject and the fact that it is very buggy and not recommended ...

Comment: Hi @mapBaker, do you have any recommendations to obtain a correct jpeg exportation using opensource satellite view ? thanks

Comment: As a new user please take the [Tour] to learn more about how this site works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "**QuickMapServices**" plugin rather then OpenLayers. I'd never recommend that anyone uses that OpenLayers plugin anymore, it's just too buggy.

This contains one fairly high 'open satellite' layer - the Mapquest Open Aerial layer:

[image]

..and when used in a print composer export, displays quite accurately without any artifacts or mis-alignments:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help ndawson ! I tried before using Mapquest, but it seems it has zoom limitations. Wherever I tried it (Europe or China), at a scale 1:200,000 is fine but if I want to zoom in (1:100,000) the symbol of the grey photograph appears. I checked my internet connection too, but it is quite stable ! Thanks again

Comment: I am sorry to add that the exportation process is not working. The jpeg coming from the print composer is just grey with the "picture-missing" logo on it. I am afraid also that  there is a kind of connection with my area of interest (Shanghai), not such an open-source friendly area maybe !

Comment: MapQuest Aerial only has high resolution for the US.  "Global coverage is provided at zoom levels 0-11. Zoom Levels 12+ are provided only in the United States (lower 48)." From: http://www.d3noob.org/2014/02/using-mapquest-open-aerial-tile-server.html

Answer (score -2):

This imagery dataset works for me too - the ESRI World Imagery. Follow link below, run script in Python to add raster layer:

https://ieqgis.wordpress.com/2014/08/09/adding-esris-online-world-imagery-dataset-to-qgis/

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Please include as much information as possible in your answer, using any links as reference.  Links can change or disappear without warning which can leave the answer with no information.  You can [edit] your answer to add as much info as possible.